# Snort rule to block the HTTP request

Tags: snort

How do I write a rule to block the request if the request will cross set threshold limit?

Example: I want if someone will request 100 times my page in 1 min then snort will block the IP.

Regards
MR

Comment: Everything you want is in the manual. http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/